# How to change the color of existing object after some action

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am drawing a simple 3D shape. The shape is read from the .obj file and the whole shape has one color.
I want to create a possibility to change the color. For example if I tap the button I want to make the structure red.

I've read a lot of tutorials but I can't figure out how to change the color (redraw element?) during the runtime. I've tried something like that in the `onDrawFrame`

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, colorBuffer);
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

But nothing is changing.

Where and how should I need to implement such action ?

//update

draw method

```
if(!initialized) {
            init(gl);
            initialized = true;
        }
        if(glCameraMatrixBuffer != null) {
            glMatrixBuffer.put(glMatrix);
            glMatrixBuffer.position(0);

            //argDrawMode3D
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            //argDraw3dCamera
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadMatrixf( glCameraMatrixBuffer );

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadMatrixf(glMatrixBuffer);
        }

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, colorBuffer);

        for(int i=0; i<parts.size(); i++){
            TDModelPart t=parts.get(i);
            Material m=t.getMaterial();

            if(m!=null){
                FloatBuffer a=m.getAmbientColorBuffer();
                FloatBuffer d=m.getDiffuseColorBuffer();
                FloatBuffer s=m.getSpecularColorBuffer();
                gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL10.GL_AMBIENT,a);
                gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL10.GL_SPECULAR,s);
                gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL10.GL_DIFFUSE,d);
            }

            gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, t.getNormalBuffer());

            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,t.getFacesCount(),GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,t.getFaceBuffer());
        }


        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

public final void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (DEBUG) {
            gl = (GL10) GLDebugHelper.wrap(gl, GLDebugHelper.CONFIG_CHECK_GL_ERROR, log);
        }
        setupDraw2D(gl);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);
        //load new preview frame as a texture, if needed
        if (frameEnqueued) {
            frameLock.lock();
            if (!isTextureInitialized) {
                initializeTexture(gl);
            } else {
                //just update the image
                //can we just update a portion(non power of two)?...seems to work
                gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, previewFrameWidth, previewFrameHeight,
                        mode, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frameData);
            }
            frameLock.unlock();
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
            frameEnqueued = false;
        }

        gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1f);
        //draw camera preview frame:
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, squareBuffer);

        //draw camera square
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        if (customRenderer != null) {
            customRenderer.setupEnv(gl);
        } else {
//          gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
//          gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, ambientLightBuffer);
//          gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLightBuffer);
//          gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, specularLightBuffer);
//          gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_POSITION, lightPositionBuffer);
//          gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);
        }

        matrixGrabber.getCurrentState(gl);

        if (performAction) {
            Log.d("ZMIANA_KOLORY", "akcja się wola");
            int[] c = new int[]{255, 0, 0};
            Vector<Float> v = markerInfo.getObjects().get(0).vectors;
            ByteBuffer vBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(v.size() * 4);
            vBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            float[] newColor = new float[c.length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                newColor[i] = (1.0f / 255) * c[i];
                newColor[3] = 1.0f;
            }

            Log.d("ZMIANA_KOLORY", newColor[0] + " " + newColor[1] + " " + newColor[2] + " " + newColor[3] + " ");

            FloatBuffer colorBuffer = vBuf.asFloatBuffer();
            colorBuffer.put(newColor);
            colorBuffer.position(0);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, colorBuffer);
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

            performAction = false;
//          Log.d("PERFORM_ACTION", "wykonuję akcję: " + actionName);
//          switch (actionName) {
//              case "Highlight":
//
//                  for(ARObject obj : markerInfo.getObjects()) {
////                        if(tmp.get)
//
//                  }
//
//                  actionName = null;
//                  performAction = false;
//                  break;
//          }
        }

        markerInfo.draw(gl);

        if (customRenderer != null) {
            customRenderer.draw(gl);
        }


        if (takeScreenshot) {
            Log.d("SCREENSHOT", "Sprawdzam touched");

            Ray r = new Ray(gl, screenWidth, screenHeight, x, y);
            Log.d("SCREENSHOT", "Near Coord =" + Arrays.toString(r.P0));
            Log.d("SCREENSHOT", "Far Coord =" + Arrays.toString(r.P1));

            takeScreenshot = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: we need to see more of your code to make sensible suggestions

Comment: @datenwolf thank you for info. To be honest my example is a bit complex so if you can tell me what would help to make a sensible suggestion I will provide specific part of the code. I added some details maybe this is enough

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a state based drawing system. State that's not active/enabled at the very moment you make a drawing call has no effect. You're enabling the color array, set the pointer and then immediately after disable it again. For the color vertex array to be taken into account, it must be enabled.

However you also seem to use a texture there. And on top of that you're using the fixed function pipeline (FFP). There are a number of interactions between textures, colors and illumination which can all lead to the color not showing up or being not turning out as you'd expect.

Do yourself a favour and start using shaders. Understanding the way the FFP works is not hard; however it grew so many state switches and data paths, that it's become very cumbersome to work with. You can either write 40+ lines of code to set up the FFP as you desire, or you can write a *single* line of shader code to the same effect.

Comment: thank you for that. in the presented case the texture is not used. I know you can see in the code but app is never entering this part, I'm working on the solid color. For sure I will read about shaders but can you say something more aboute the states ? The thing that it need to be active ? Is this the problem that I can not change the color ?